# Can indexes use existing indexes while building

Tags: sql-server-2008

In Sql Server 2008, do indexes always refer to the table data when building, or can they make use of other existing indexes while building?

Answer (score 1):

When you rebuild an index it can use it's own data to rebuild from, or it can use the data from the base table (or the clustered index if the table has a clustered index).  It won't use data from another non-clustered index.